# After Yosemite, compiler can not find Portaudio

Tags: compiler-errors, osx-yosemite, portaudio

After my mac updating Yosemite, i cant compile C program with Portaudio.

in Terminal, I make below

```
Cproglams:
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2
LOADLIBES = -lportaudio
```

Then,

```
ld: library not found for -lportaudio
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

above error comes...

Anyone knows a cause?

---

+
with re-install portaudio and copy alias to Xcode 10.10 SDK folder, library was found.
but this error comes...

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libportaudio.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x62 0x6F 0x6F 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x6D 0x61 0x72 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libportaudio.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_Pa_CloseStream", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_GetDeviceInfo", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_GetErrorText", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_Initialize", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_OpenStream", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_StartStream", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
"_Pa_Terminate", referenced from:
_main in fuzz-b30cf8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

...mmm,,, help me!
thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same thing grrrrr...

Comment: i found a solution!
A cause is symbolic link.

compile with absolute path for libportaudio -> success!